# XML File Won't Generate in SQL

Tags: sql, xml

I'm attempting to create an XML file if invoices and I believe I have the code correct, but it's not generating the XML file. I've googled, but don't seem to have the correct keywords to find my issue since I'm not sure what the issue is. What could be causing the XML file to not be created?

```
USE AP

SELECT 
    InvoiceNumber, 
    InvoiceDate, 
    InvoiceTotal, 
    InvoiceLineItemDescription, 
    InvoiceLineItemAmount
        FROM 
            Invoices JOIN InvoiceLineItems
        ON 
            Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID 
    WHERE Invoices.InvoiceID IN (
        SELECT Invoices.InvoiceID
            FROM Invoices JOIN InvoiceLineItems
         ON Invoices.InvoiceID = InvoiceLineItems.InvoiceID 
    GROUP BY Invoices.InvoiceID
    HAVING COUNT(InvoiceLineItemDescription) > 1)

ORDER BY InvoiceDate 

FOR XML PATH ('InvoiceNumber'), ROOT('Invoices');
```

This is what I get when I execute the query:

[image]

This is the sample data:

[image]

When I take out the "HAVING COUNT(InvoiceLineItemDescription) > 1" code it creates the XML file, but I want to only pull invoices that have line items. Nothing I've tried is making it work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sample data from your query and desired results/xml formatting would be helpful

Comment: I'll get that to you as soon as I can. Computer freaked out and had to restart. Now I can't connect to the database engine. Gotta do some troubleshooting.

Comment: Always at the worst time

Comment: Got it working. Turns out the service got shot off when my computer freaked out.

I ran the query without the XML code and it's not returning anything. That's probably why it's not returning an XML link.

Comment: Okay, I took out the line "HAVING COUNT(InvoiceLineItemDescription) > 1" and it generates an XML link. I don't want the link to return the invoices that don't don't have any line items. Is there a way to code this that makes that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know enough about your data, but the answer might be very simple:

```
HAVING COUNT(InvoiceLineItemDescription) > 0)
```

You checked for `>1` while you were grouping by `InvoiceId`. If my magic crystall ball works better than your *freaked out computer* :-D, I assume, that you have one `InvoiceNumber` per `InvoiceId` and there is exactly one `InvoiceLineItemDescription` per `Invoice`. With `>1` you'd find 2 or more, but not 1...

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Your crystal ball does indeed work better than my freaked out computer. And your explanation does make a great deal of sense. Thank you for your assistance. I really appreciate you taking the time to look this over.